Restricting an ionic angular application to be installed on a rooted/jailbrake ios device/simulator
I am using ionic with capacitor and angular in my application. I want to restrict application to be installed on a rooted/jailbrake ios device/simulator.
I am using cordova-plugin-iroot plugin.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-iroot
But I am unable to verify/check it in IOS platform. When I run the app in simulator it is working fine and not restricting.
Can anyone please suggest how to check it in ios simulator or cordova-plugin-iroot plugin does not work for ios platform.

This plugin is obsolete and does not work with current ionic versions. I think this is a fool’s errand. Once a device is jailbroken, all bets are off. Unless an environment chooses to provide a clue, an app can’t even know if it’s running on a real device or an emulator.

@StackoverBlows Is there any ways/any plugin which can be used for this requirement in ionic 6?

Not that i know of. I never used a plugin to prevent my app to be installed on jailbroken phones myself as this is just a waste of time like i stated above.
